# In TensorFlow development, how do they control what code to open source or not?

Tags: tensorflow, software-design

TensorFlow is a big project, right? In TensorFlow development, how do they control what code to open source or not? I'm not a SDE and I'm curious about how they did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technology they use is called Copybara, which is open sourced (naturally), and you can read the code and anything else you would like to know at https://github.com/google/copybara.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! That's awesome! In fact, for a big project, I'm curious about how they control the dependencies between any classes or functions among the open source code and closed source code. But I think I don't have time to read that code...because reading the source code of TensorFlow is really a big project to me.